# Fullcalendar's remoteEventSource is removing all sources

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar with some buttons that add and remove json sources.
Script adds sources perfectly, but when I try to remove one source, it removes all sources.
There's something I missed somewhere, maybe someone can help me.

```
$('.mycheckboxes').click(function() {

    // retrieve calendar ID from clicked checkbox
    var cal = $(this).attr('id');

    // define a json event source
    var src = {
        url: 'calendarJSON.php', 
        type: 'GET', 
        data: { calendar_id: cal }
    }


    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', src );
    } else {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', src );

    }
});
```

Why is it deleting all events sources? how should I specify the one I want to remove?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As described in [the (very good) docu](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/removeEventSource/) it is enough to pass the url of your event source.

So try this code :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', 'calendarJSON.php' );
```

Here you can find a working example http://jsfiddle.net/domi27/bQXYp/1/

Answer (score 1):

Like [domi27](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892318/domi27)  stated already, fullcalendar allows to pass as event source the URL. But it also allows to pass an array as you do. And you're right. In your case, all sources are removed.

I'll fixed this with a little trick: Append something to your URL to let fullcalendar distinguish the event sources!

e.g.

```
// define a json event source
var src = {
    url: 'calendarJSON.php?dummy=' + cal, 
    type: 'GET', 
    data: { calendar_id: cal }
}
```